# CodeIgniter URL Rewrite

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, url-rewriting, get

I have found so many examples of URL Rewrite in CI, but not a final and good solution, i have url like this

www.somesite.com/index.php/tehnicki/tekstovi

I want to have url like this

www.somesite.com/about.html

This **about** is GET Variable, that is going in MySql Query, it will be no number it will be some NAME, how to do that?

And what i have to write in tehnicki controller to take that GET Variable, is there any helper in CI for MySQL Attack, or i have to write it on my own :)

Comment: Can i simply be done somethin like this? RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php/tehnicki/tekstovi?naslov=$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's see, it seems messed up and it doesn't make sense but I'll give you what you need.

First we will have to remove the index.php file :
- use this as .htaccess

```
//.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|Skin|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

next, in your config.php set index_page to an empty string

```
// application/config/config.php
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

on the same file, scroll to url_suffix, and set it to .html

```
// application/config/config.php
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

now head to your routes.php and apply a rewrite rule

```
// application/config/routes.php
$route['about'] = "tehnicki/tekstovi";
```

I'll quickly explain what I did here so you get how it works:
1- we removed the index.php section of the url in order to clean it
2- we added a url suffix that will be generated on all the pages
3- we applied a rewrite rule that will match /about.html to the controller tehnicki and the action tekstovi (tehnicki/tekskovi)